# Delete tracked file with GIT that isnt in the repo?

Tags: git

I have a new file being tracked by GIT but not in a repository. How can I delete this file from my machine?

This is the output from GIT:

```
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   images/.directory
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean; can you post the output of:

`git status`

Comment: unstage the commit and delete the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove it from the index and clean it:

```
$ git reset HEAD images/.directory
$ git clean -fd images/.directory
```